# Tables overflowing with CSS in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-table, overflow

I'm having trouble getting my table to behave. The content keeps overflowing and my attempts to restrict it are not producing the desired effect.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="repeatingdiv">
 <div class="hastitle">Some title</div>  
 <div class="hastable">
  <table>
   <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>     
   <tfoot><tr><th></th></tr></tfoot>
   <tbody>   
    <tr>
     <td class="col1">Col 1</td>
     <td class="col2">Col 2</td>
     <td class="col3">Col 3</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

I then have some style. The `td's` are overflowing, but I didn't have any luck setting their `overflow to hidden/auto`. I did have better luck setting overflow in the `hastable` class that contains the table. But I'm still having trouble getting [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) to respect the `width` distribution for the 3 columns: `30%, 35%, 35%`. I also tried setting `min-width`, but still no luck. I have several of these tables on the page, and each one takes its own width. Any help with this table mess?

```
.repeatingdiv { }
.hastitle      { margin:0 10px; padding:3px 3px 1px 6px; }       
.hastable      { overflow:hidden; 
                 text-overflow: ellipsis; 
                 margin:10px; 
                 padding:10px; 
               }
table          { }
table tbody    { width: 100%; }
tr    { width: 100%; }
td.col1     { width:30%; min-width:30%; }
td.col2  { width:35%; min-width:35%; }
td.col3  { width:35%; min-width:35%; }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tables are notoriously difficult to style. Try adding this to your CSS:

```
table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100% /* or whatever fixed width */; }
```

I'd also suggest using actual HTML `COL` / `COLGROUP` elements to define your columns, as so:

```
<table>
 <colgroup class="col1" />
 <colgroup class="col2" />
 <colgroup class="col3" />
 <thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>     
 <tfoot><tr><th></th></tr></tfoot>
 <tbody>   
  <tr>
   <td>Col 1</td>
   <td>Col 2</td>
   <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Do take note that, despite this, cells with overflowing data *will* force the containing cell, row, and table to expand to fit. CSS `overflow: auto` / `hidden` / `scroll` do not affect cells.

Ref:

- [CSS: Table Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-table-layout),
- [HTML: COLGROUP](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-COLGROUP)

Comment: Overflow should work in cells according to spec. In practice `hidden` works but scrolling doesn't, except in WebKit.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use white-space: nowrap in a td element and I noticed that the width of my table suddenly ballooned even though I set the width to 100%; but, after adding table-layout: fixed to the CSS that fixed the problem!

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;` saved my bacon in FireFox. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your table in a div and set overflow for the div.

```
<div style='overflow:scroll;'>
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
</div>
```